Py-Cord function not responding when accessing permissions
This is the strangest problem I have ever had with this library. My code works fine, but this command (below) does not respond with anything. However, the program does not output any error.
@admin.command(name = "staffrole", description = "Toggle a role that has permissions to use this bot's admin commands")
@guild_only()
async def staffrole(ctx, role: discord.Option(Union[discord.Role])):
    print('This prints successfully')
    admin = ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_server
    print("This does not print. I have no idea why.")
    if not admin:
        return await ctx.respond("You must have \"Manage Server\" or \"Administrator\" permission in this server to use this.", ephemeral=True)
    try:
        with open(f"StaffRoles/{ctx.guild.id}", 'x') as _:
            pass
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    with open(f"StaffRoles/{ctx.guild.id}", 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.readlines()
        if f"{role.id}\n" in filedata:
            with open(f'StaffRoles/{ctx.guild.id}', 'w') as filew:
                filedata = ''.join(filedata)
                filedata = filedata.replace(f'{str(role.id)}\n', '')
                filew.write(filedata)
            await ctx.respond(f"Removed {str(role)} from the Staff List!", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            with open(f'StaffRoles/{ctx.guild.id}', 'a') as filea:
                filea.write(f"{str(role.id)}\n")
            await ctx.respond(f"Added {str(role)} to the Staff List!", ephemeral=True)

All necessary variables are defined, and as shown in the code, the first print statement works fine but the second one does not. Given this, I must assume that the issue lies within the permission access. My bot has full intents and works on my test server, but not in a real server not owned by me. If it matters, the bot does not have Administrator access in the server that this test does not work on. It does have mange_server perms, though.
I attempted to change
admin = ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator or ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_server

to
perms = [perm[0] for perm in member.guild_permissions if perm[1]]

But I could not even get the list without the same issue.
Any advice?

ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_server would raise an error because manage_server does not exist, meaning the following code will not run.
You should use manage_guild instead.
You are not getting an error because you are improperly handling errors in your on_application_command_error event.
